# HTML Form Validation make sure the last 2 characters in input field are alphabets

Tags: html, regex, validation, input, pattern-matching

I would like to make sure that HTML input field contains the last 2 characters as Alphabets and not any other characters. Is there a way to do it from the HTML pattern itself?
For example:
´Allowed values are:´

```
123554BA
1248848585GH
8484884rd
```

So basically the last 2  characters have to be alphabets if not then an error message is displayed and form is not submitted. Is there a way to do it from the HTML side itself using some patter or regex? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
  <input name="x" type="text" size="10" pattern=".*[a-zA-Z]{2}" required>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```